# Compiling .cpp into .exe with cygwin?

Tags: c++, compilation

I tried to compile a .cpp into an .exe with two different ways, the first (following a tutorial) was by going to the files location (C:\Users\me\Desktop\CPP Files) and typing cmd and opening a prompt then typing:  g++ main.cpp main.exe (i also tried the other way around, with the .exe first) and got this error: 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

on the cygwin prompt i got this error: cc1plus: fatal error: klog_main.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

How can i fix this/what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are not compiling from the cygwin terminal

Comment: `C:\Users\me\Desktop\CPP Files`  I recommend against ever putting a space in a path or a file name when using c++. Remember that most compilers work with on the command line / shell and a space in the shell separates arguments causing you to have to quote the paths.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it on the cygwin terminal as well and got this error: cc1plus: fatal error: main.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: You were in the wrong folder in the terminal. `main.cpp` was not in the folder that you were in when you executed g++

Comment: Side note: Cygwin can be a nuisance. Unless you need the POSIX compatibility layer Cygwin provides, [consider using msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301).